# empty parameterbag object on request

Tags: symfony, curl

I am running a json restapi service on ubuntu with symfony2 framework.

Everything was working fine but for security and performance reasons we moved to amazon ec2 with rds.

Now i am facing a strange problem if i call the api with curl it works ok until i use some characters on the body parameters like accents (´).

i copy and paste the `/etc/php5` and `/etc/apache2` config folder from the old server to the new server, still not working.

i also match the locale on both server. debugging the symfony2 request object i realize that the parameterbag object when using an special character like (`á`) is empty for all the parameters.

Comment: All special characters in urls and headers must be encoded, according to the rfc. POST parameters are `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which mean every special character must be encoded like in an url.

Comment: but it was working on the old server. On the header the content-type is defined as application/json

Comment: Use the symfony configuration check.php to check your system to meet all requirements

Comment: yes Benny, it only recommends to install apc, nothing else.